# Override all class methods at once to do the same thing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a 3rd party API that provides a single Python wrapper class which contains ~50 methods that do nothing except accepting a set of arbitrary parameters. I am then meant to make my own class and override each of those methods to do what I actually want. My issues with this:

- it's a lot of methods to be overriding, and if they change the API I have to make my class perfectly match theirs: maintenance is yucky.
- I use multiprocessing and would like to package all the data into msgs, put them in a queue, and handle the results in another process, so I don't want to put my data processing logic into this class.

Stripped down version of their class:

```
class TheirWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def func1(self, a, b, c):
        pass
    def func2(self, d, e, f):
        pass
    ... and ~50 more
```

And stripped down version of what I have working:

```
class MyWrapper:
    def addToQueue(self, localvars):
        # adds calling function name and localvars to queue (after removing self from localvars)
    def func1(self, a, b, c):
        self.addToQueue(locals())
    def func1=2(self, d, e, f):
        self.addToQueue(locals())
    ... and ~50 more
```

Considering that I do precisely the same thing in each overridden method (`self.addToQueue(locals())`), I would like to be able to override ALL of their methods at once (except `__init__`) to do that one thing. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do it using inspection of contents of `TheirWrapper` with `dir()`:

```
import inspect


class TheirWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def func1(self, a, b, c):
        pass
    def func2(self, d, e, f):
        pass


class MyWrapper:
    def addToQueue(self, localvars):
        # your implementation
        print(localvars)


### You can orginize this block into decorator or metaclass and make more general
def add_func(func_name):
    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        signature = inspect.signature(getattr(TheirWrapper, func_name))
        bind = signature.bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
        arguments = dict(bind.arguments)
        arguments['func_name'] = func_name
        self.addToQueue(arguments)
    return add


for name in dir(TheirWrapper):
    if not name.startswith('__'):
        setattr(MyWrapper, name, add_func(name))
###

w = MyWrapper()
w.func1(1, 2, 3)
# prints {'self': <__main__.MyWrapper object at 0x00000000030262E8>, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'func_name': 'func1'}
```

[docs for inspect.signature & bind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object)

[docs for dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: Very nice solution and I learned something. Unfortunately `addToQueue` needs the calling function's name; it currently uses `sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name`, but now that returns `add` instead of the actual overridden functions' names. Don't suppose the original name can be kept?

Comment: @fantabolous please see the updated answer. Now you have `'func_name': 'func1'` in passed `localvars` dictionary.

Comment: thank you, that worked to get the function names. I realize now though that args / kwargs isn't working for me either: all the functions' parameters are in a list of values in args without their parameter names, and without the parameter names I can't do much with them. e.g. for func1 rather than getting a=1, b=2, and c=3, I just get args=[1,2,3].

Comment: @fantabolous updated one more time. Now you get a dictionary with argument names as keys.

Comment: Count me incredibly impressed. It works perfectly. Thank you so much.