# How can I avoid code repetition when overriding many properties in a child class in the same way?

Tags: python, overriding

I have a class in which I have properties that are returning arrays. For simplicity, let's consider them constant:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._b = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7])

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
```

Now, I have another class which is inheriting `MyClass` and it is interpolating the data, for example:

```
class Interpolator(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, vector):
        super().__init__()
        self._vector = np.array(vector)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, self._a)

    @property
    def b(self):
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, self._b)
```

Now, the issue is that I have 2 classes like `MyClass` and each one of them consists of ~30 properties.

Is there a way to override all properties without doing it one by one? I was having a look also at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232546/override-all-class-methods-at-once-to-do-the-same-thing) but I am not sure if/how I can apply it to my problem.

Comment: @MoRe Ergonomics such as code completion, for one. With explicit `property`s, your IDE can tell you what properties actually exist.

Comment: this really feels like an anti-pattern

Comment: don't use the term `attributes` here - use the term `methods`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Um... no one has used the term "attributes"?

Comment: @AKX oh I meant to say `methods` instead of `properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your superclass to "proxy"/"trampoline" those properties via a function you can override in a subclass:

```
import numpy as np


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._b = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7])

    def _get_property(self, v):
        return v

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._get_property(self._a)

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._get_property(self._b)


class Interpolator(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, vector):
        super().__init__()
        self._vector = np.array(vector)

    def _get_property(self, v):
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit different approach, perhaps useful if you need to control which properties should actually be interpolatable

```py
import numpy as np

def interpolatable(f):
    setattr(f, "interpolatable", True)
    return f

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._b = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7])
        self._c = np.array([1,2,3,4])

    @property
    @interpolatable
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    @interpolatable
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c


class Interpolator(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, vector):
        super().__init__()
        self._vector = np.array(vector)

    def _interpolate(self, target):
        print("Interpolating")
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, target)

    def __getattribute__(self, __name: str):
         v = super().__getattribute__(__name)
         a = getattr(type(self), __name, None)
         if type(a) == property and getattr(getattr(a, "fget", None), "interpolatable", False):
             return self._interpolate(v)
         return v
```