# Method is not overridden when using multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107191/how-can-i-avoid-code-repetition-when-overriding-many-properties-in-a-child-class), I am now trying to implement the answer I got.
However, now I am facing another problem which involves (I think) multiple inheritance.

Basically, I have an `Interpolator` for my main class which has several properties. One of them has sub properties defined with a sub class and I am not able to override the method in there. Any help please?

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._sub = SubClass()

    def _get_class_value(self, name):
        value = getattr(self, '_'+name)
        return value

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self._get_class_value('time')

    @property
    def a(self):
        print('calling a')
        return self._get_class_value('a')

    @property
    def sub(self):
        print('calling sub')
        return self._sub


class SubClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._k1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

    def _get_sub_value(self, name):
        value = getattr(self, '_'+name)
        return value

    @property
    def k1(self):
        print('calling k1')
        return self._get_sub_value('k1')


class Interpolator(MyClass, SubClass):
    def __init__(self, vector):
        super().__init__()
        self._vector = np.array(vector)

    def _get_class_value(self, name):
        print('overriding main class', name)
        return self._interpolate(name)

    def _get_sub_value(self, name):
        print('overriding sub class', name)
        return self._interpolate(name)

    def _interpolate(self, name):
        value = getattr(self, '_'+name)
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, value)

interp = Interpolator([1.5, 2.5])
value_a = interp.a
value_k1 = interp.sub.k1
```

Running the code above, I never get `'overriding sub class'`:

```
calling a
overriding main class a
calling sub
calling k1
```

Comment: `interp.sub` is a `SubClass`, not `Interpolator`. Why should anything be overridden?

Answer (score 0):

class MyClass init self._sub = SubClass() will be a new Class.

you use self._sub = SubClass()

The result will be class SubClass _get_sub_value.

class Interpolator _get_sub_value will not be used.

```py
import numpy as np


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self._a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        # self._sub = SubClass()  # delete

    def _get_class_value(self, name):
        value = getattr(self, '_' + name)
        return value

    @property
    def time(self):
        return self._get_class_value('time')

    @property
    def a(self):
        print('calling a')
        return self._get_class_value('a')

    @property
    def sub(self):
        print('calling sub')
        return self  # return self


class SubClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._k1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

    def _get_sub_value(self, name):
        value = getattr(self, '_' + name)
        return value

    @property
    def k1(self):
        print('calling k1')
        return self._get_sub_value('k1')


class Interpolator(MyClass, SubClass):
    def __init__(self, vector):
        MyClass.__init__(self)  # Inheritance
        SubClass.__init__(self)  # Inheritance
        self._vector = np.array(vector)

    def _get_class_value(self, name):
        print('overriding main class', name)
        return self._interpolate(name)

    def _get_sub_value(self, name):
        print('overriding sub class', name)
        return self._interpolate(name)

    def _interpolate(self, name):
        value = getattr(self, '_' + name)
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, value)
        return np.interp(self._vector, self._time, value)


interp = Interpolator([1.5, 2.5])
value_a = interp.a
value_k1 = interp.sub.k1
```